# What is the correct way to check errors with firebase auth methods?

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

I recently started using firebase. I am creating a simple app containing email password authentication. When the user submits the form there are two possibilities.

- If there is any error then Form will show error will remain visible.
- If there is no error Form will hide and remove error.

The loader needs to be hide after processing in either case. The relevant part of the code is.

```
let error = false;
auth
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .catch(err => {
        if (err) error = true;
        RegisterForm.setError(err.message);
    })
    .then(x => {
        if (!error) {
            RegisterFormDialog.close();
        }
    })
    .finally(() => {
        MainLoader.hide();
    });
```

The above code is working completely fine but the problem is that I have to create an extra variable `error` is the outer scope and then check it inside `then()`. Is there any callback what will only run if there are no errors. Because `then()` is called even when errors are there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual practice for all methods that return a promise (not just Firebase) is to put `then` before `catch` when handling the results:

```
let error = false;
auth
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(x => {
        RegisterFormDialog.close();
    })
    .catch(err => {
        if (err) error = true;
        RegisterForm.setError(err.message);
    })
    .finally(() => {
        MainLoader.hide();
    });
```

If the promise resolves successfully, the `then` callback will be invoked.  Otherwise, the `catch` callback will be invoked.  But never both.

Comment: Works fine. Thanks